# Need to convert a vertical data set to horizontal with a one to many relationship

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

Like to make a new data set where column 1 is distinct categorical variable and column 2 through to Column X, are the associated values of A.  This is a one to many relationship.

When using spread got an error message given the 1 to many relationship

```
library(tidyr)
new_data <- spread(original_data, `State name`, `Park Location`)

Col 1 Col 2  Transform to  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4 
A       C                    A     C    B     A
A       B                    B     A
A       A
B       A 

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 687 rows:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with making my dataframe in 'wide' structure while trying using spread() function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412910/problems-with-making-my-dataframe-in-wide-structure-while-trying-using-spread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a sequence column by 'Col1'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
original_data %>%
   group_by(Col1) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   spread(rn, Col2)
```

Comment: I can see the new tibble creates the horizontal data set I'm looking for.  And creates new column names of 1 through 7 given the frequency of the 1 to many relationship in the data, I just needed to convert back into a data frame. TY